# Should we pass the transpose of a data into sklearn StandardScaler()?

Tags: scale

I possess a dataset where each row corresponds to distinct mobile applications and the columns represent Key Performance Indicators (KPIs). I'm currently wondring whether it's necessary to normalize the transposed version of the data before applying PCA. thank you

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGuy6.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGuy6.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

For `sklearn`, the shape of the training features should be: `number of samples/instances x features`. Your data structure is `apps x KPIs`. If you feed that data in without transposing it, the algorithms will interpret your KPIs to be features, and each app to be a sample from KPI-space. If you feed in transposed data instead, the interpretation will be that each KPI is a sample characterised by its 'app signature' (its values across apps).

The question is what makes more sense for your data or task. To me it seems like you might want to cluster *apps* according to their KPI characteristics/features, which is akin to saying that your apps are the samples, and your KPIs are the features. Thus you'd feed the data in without transposition (`apps x KPIs`).

`PCA` requires scaled data, so it would perform better if you first scaled your data, and then fed it into PCA:

```
#Fit a scaler and use it to scale the data
scaler = StandardScaler().fit(X)
X_scaled = scaler.transform(X)

#Fit PCA model
pca = PCA().fit(X_scaled)
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's clear and makes sense to me, in fact, I would cluster the apps according to their KPIs.